# Enlarge the first slide of a carousel

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, carousel

I tried to create a carousel as follows. But I couldn't make it work. I also tried to use Center Mode in the slick carousel. But it only applies to the slide in the middle. If there is a method or library that can enlarge the first slide in this way, please indicate. thank you.
[image: The carousel i want]

Comment: Please show us you code and what you have tried.

Comment: Ive added a generic answer below, but if you add your actual code we can have a better look and deliver a more specific answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can maybe look into adding an "active" class to an element of the slide - so then you can apply appropriate CSS to the active class and it will only affect the active element. This means that one of the images will be "active" and you can do whatever to it, and when it slides another will become "active" and inherit the properties, whilst the one from before will lose them.

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_active_element.asp

Answer (score 1):

Independed of your actual slide usecase you can target the first element among a group of siblings with the css `:first-child` pseudo class (see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child).

Ive added a simple example of how to use it.

To transfer it to your swiper you will have to apply the `:first-child` pseudo class to the class wrapping your individual slides.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}

.entry {
  font-size: 15px;
}

.entry:first-child {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="entry">Entry</div>
  <div class="entry">Entry</div>
  <div class="entry">Entry</div>
  <div class="entry">Entry</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply. I tried it. Your answer made the first slider bigger but when I swipe to the next slide the new slide didn't get bigger. I want the slide that comes up as the first slide to be enlarged.

Comment: For that youll need some indication trough the sliders js of what is the currently active slide. Most slider plugins already provide such modifier classes like "current" or "active". What slider javascript are u using?

Comment: Thank you. I get your point. I am currently trying on the slick slider

Comment: @RuLee `.slick-active` should be the class youre looking for (judging by the code from https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/blob/master/slick/slick.js).

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this design through these codes:

for the first image

```
 .slick-slide.slick-current.slick-active {        
   .your class {
        width: 100%;   
    }
 }
```

for the following images

```
.slick-slide.slick-active {  
  .your class {
        width: 80%;   
    }
 }
```

you can add first-child if you like to design specific class